# Moving a background in a timer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How does one move the background image in a timer using cocos2d.

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
```

What would be set in this method to move the background only on its y axis? I would like to scroll the map/background downwards as if the player is moving upwards.

I would like to then call this update method somehow every second or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)delta

{
backgrd.position = ccp(backgrd.position.x,backgrd.position.y-10);
}
```

In your init:

```
-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
if(self)
{
//init your backgrd and stuff..
[self schedule:@selector(update:) interval: 1.0];
}
return self;
}
```